# A confused about database structure and displacement on django admin

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

I am currently working on django and get confused about how to design the model.
Right now, I have a table named 'Reactionmeta' which structure like below:

```
 1      2         3              4                 5            6
```

reaction   name   metabolite1  stoichiometry1 ....... metabolite60 stoichiometry60 (stoichiometry1 corresponds to metabolite1 and so on so forth)

(P.S: I have to claim that each stoichiometry correspond to one metabolites in the reaction, like a + b -> 2c + d(the number is the stoichiometry)
However, one metabolite may has different stoichiometry, because they may involved in different reactions.
For example:   a + 2b + c -> d + e + f;     2a + b -> h + j (metabolite a has different stoichiometry in two reactions)

some of the reactions, contains 2 metabolites, thus this reaction have value in 6 columns and no value from column 7-122.
And some of the reactions contains more than 40 metabolites, so they have values in majority of columns.

My question is, I created the class and registered in the admin.py, and when I clicked on one reaction in adminsite and all the columns are displayed even though some of fields are blank, like below:

In that case, how can only display those fields with values and hide the fields without values? Or is there is any other way to modify the database structure or class structure to display the metabolites and stoichiometry only this reaction involves?

Thank you!!!!

[image]

Comment: So actually you want to model chemical reactions in a database. However to me it looks like your current approach can only model either side of the reaction equation, but not both. Or am I missing something?